# Recursive binary tree gives memory access error

Tags: c, memory

We need to create a binary tree which contains content of textfiles. The pointer selection_a and selection_b pointing to another textfile in the direcetory.

The structure of the textfiles is following:
1. line: Title
2. line: OptionA
3. line: OptionB
4. - n. line: Text.

The first file is given as paremeter while starting the program. All files should be saved at the beginning of the programm.
Then the Text of the first file shows, and User can input A or B to continue. Based on the selection, the text of File Option A/B is shown and he can decide again.

The last file of a tree contains no Options: 2. and 3. line are "-\n".

The Problem is, this code only reads all the option A files of the first tree. It doesn't read in any B-Options.
In the end, the program shows a memory access error.

I know the code may be kind of caotic, but we are beginners in programming.
Hope anybody can help.
Here is the code:

```
struct story_file
{
  char *title;
  char *text;
  struct story_file *selection_a;
  struct story_file *selection_b;
};
```

Comment: Learn [how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and creating a [MCVE].

Comment: `strcat(filename, txt);` is wrong because filename` points to `argv[1]` which may not be large enough to append ".txt".

Comment: `char ch = getc(input);` must be `int ch = getc(input);` to be able to compare with EOF.

Comment: `current->text = strcat(current->text,lines);` is wrong because you did not allocate space for this.

Comment: Do you got any idea how to solve this problem, we don't really know how to continue :/

Comment: thanks for that but its not our main problem. I can't imagine that the problem that no B-Path of the tree is saved correlates with this problem. All A-Files can be read in correct without memory errors. I guess the program dosn't move to the else where it shoult read in the B-Files

Comment: It is the case in `readingRows` where `line_counter > 2`.

Comment: You should take your program in the debugger to find exactly where the error occurrs.

Comment: the error ist not there anymore after i changed char ch to int ch. But anyway, the program still only prints all A options. It does not access the If, where it should save the B-option.

Comment: could it be that there is no abort condition. We think that line counter never is 2.

Answer (score 2):

In `readingRows()` you have assigned string literal to `current->text`

```
  current->text = "";
```

Now `current->text` holds read only string and you are modifying it in strcat()

```
current->text = strcat(current->text,lines);
```

This will lead to undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is in `current->text`

First, you set it to `current->text = "";` which makes it point to the empty string (and a read-only literal). You should set it to zero:

```
 current->text = 0;
```

Then you want to append text to it but forget to allocate memory for it in:

```
 current->text = strcat(current->text,lines);
```

You should do:

```
int currlen, linelen;
linelen= strlen(lines);
if (current->text) currlen= strlen(current->text); else currlen= 0;
char *newtext= malloc(currlen+linelen+1);
if (current->text) strcpy(newtext, current->text); else *newtext= 0;
strcat(newtext, lines);
if (current->text) free(current->text);
current->text= newtext;
```